# Do something in jquery if element has exact property & value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something in jquery if my element has a given property & value.

This is what I'm trying that doesn't work:

```
if ($('.myElement').css('opacity','1')){
    console.log('test');
}
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second paramter of `css()` sets the style, not passing that parameter returns the current style for you to check against a string :

```
if ($('.myElement').css('opacity') == '1'){
    console.log('test');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the css style we use `$(element).css(propertyname);`

to set style we use `$(element).css(propertyname,value);`

```
if ($('.myElement').css('opacity') == 1){
    console.log('test');
}
```

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)